# how to add multiple images for a contact in joomla 2.5?

Tags: contacts, joomla2.5

I am using the joomla built in contacts extension for adding contacts. In this extension there is a section for contact details. There we can an image for a contact.

But I want to display 2 images for a single contact. How will I so this?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla `com_contact` extension is not designed to display multiple images for the contact.

Consider following options:

1. Create 1 image that combines 2 images (side-by-side or vertical)
2. Add images in contact description with `style="float:right"`
3. Overload template in `/templates/your_template/html/com_contacts/contact/default.php`
4. Look at other extensions, for example [aiContactSafe](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/contact-forms/7901)